# Joining multiple tables without duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables as follows

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 
(
    [ID] [INT]    NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR] (50)   NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE tbl2 
(
    [ID] [INT]    NULL,
    [TranNo] [VARCHAR] (50)   NULL,
    [TranName] [VARCHAR] (50)   NULL  
) ;    

CREATE TABLE tbl3 
(
    [ID] [INT]    NULL,
    [ResultNo] [VARCHAR] (50)   NULL,
    [ResultName] [VARCHAR] (50)   NULL
) ;    

INSERT INTO tbl1 
VALUES (1,'Andy'), (2,'Lisa')

INSERT INTO tbl2 
VALUES (1, 'A1', 'Order'),
       (1, 'A2', 'Order'),
       (1, 'A3', 'Order'),
       (1, 'A4', 'Delivery'),
       (2, 'A5', 'Order'),
       (2, 'A6', 'Delivery'),
       (2, 'A7', 'Delivery')
 
INSERT INTO tbl3
VALUES (1, 'R1', 'Pending'),
       (1, 'R2', 'Success'),
       (2, 'R3', 'Success')
```

This is my query

```
Select 
    tbl1.*,
    tbl2.TranNo, tbl2.TranName, 
    tbl3.ResultNo, tbl3.ResultName
from 
    tbl1
left outer join
    tbl2 on tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID
left outer join
    tbl3 on tbl1.ID = tbl3.ID
```

Result: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c4bd6c/1/0)

| ID | Name | TranNo | TranName | ResultNo | ResultName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | A1 | Order | R1 | Pending |
| 1 | Andy | A1 | Order | R2 | Success |
| 1 | Andy | A2 | Order | R1 | Pending |
| 1 | Andy | A2 | Order | R2 | Success |
| 1 | Andy | A3 | Order | R1 | Pending |
| 1 | Andy | A3 | Order | R2 | Success |
| 1 | Andy | A4 | Delivery | R1 | Pending |
| 1 | Andy | A4 | Delivery | R2 | Success |
| 2 | Lisa | A5 | Order | R3 | Success |
| 2 | Lisa | A6 | Delivery | R3 | Success |
| 2 | Lisa | A7 | Delivery | R3 | Success |

I want a no duplicate result / no extra result like this

| ID | Name | TranNo | TranName | ResultNo | ResultName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | A1 | Order | R1 | Pending |
| 1 | Andy | A2 | Order | R2 | Success |
| 1 | Andy | A3 | Order |  |  |
| 1 | Andy | A4 | Delivery |  |  |
| 2 | Lisa | A5 | Order | R3 | Success |
| 2 | Lisa | A6 | Delivery |  |  |
| 2 | Lisa | A7 | Delivery |  |  |

or

| ID | Name | TranNo | TranName | ResultNo | ResultName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | A1 | Order | R1 | Pending |
|  |  | A2 | Order | R2 | Success |
|  |  | A3 | Order |  |  |
|  |  | A4 | Delivery |  |  |
| 2 | Lisa | A5 | Order | R3 | Success |
|  |  | A6 | Delivery |  |  |
|  |  | A7 | Delivery |  |  |

Thanks for those of you who can help

Comment: How do you choose "Pending" for Andy:A1 and "Success" for Andy:A2? And why does Andy:A3 have no result? You need to explain your logic.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `no duplicate` result. Just the `TranNo`?  It is essential to understand the columns you want to be queried. Sometimes, filtering the result (when you don't have a lot of records) should be done with code (at business logic).

Comment: You made such a great start with your question, not many people take the time to add the DDL+DML like you did. But you need to ensure your question is complete and explains the logic behind the results.

Comment: This is just an example, I have more complex data. This example only wants the results from tbl2 and tbl3 according to the number of records in each table without any extra results, while tbl1 follows the number of rows from tbl2 and tbl3. With ID as the key of each table. maybe by using aggregate function or pivot function, i hope someone can help me to output my desired result. thanks

Comment: You haven't explained the logic as per my question above... i.e. why did you choose "Pending" for Andy:A1 and "Success" for Andy:A2? But if I am honest this looks like a display problem not a query problem.

Comment: as I said this data is only an example, and indeed what I hope is that the results displayed are what I want, without any extra results appearing, according to the number of records from each table with only the ID as key

Comment: My point is we can't help you create that unless you explain the rules for creating it... you are somehow choosing to display select data, but you are not explaining how to choose that data. Until you provide that explanation no one can assist you. I've asked you a very simple question, twice, and both times you have chosen not to answer. Therefore I cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to zip the transaction (tbl2) and result (tbl3) rows together by ID and a generated row number. Those results can then joined back with tbl1.

Something like:

```
;WITH CTE_T AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TranNo) AS RN
    FROM tbl2
),
CTE_R AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ResultNo) AS RN
    FROM tbl3
),
CTE_TR AS (
    SELECT
      COALESCE(T.ID, R.ID) AS ID,
      COALESCE(T.RN, R.RN) AS RN,
      T.TranNo, T.TranName, R.ResultNo, R.ResultName
    FROM CTE_T T
    FULL OUTER JOIN CTE_R R
        ON R.ID = T.ID
        AND R.RN = T.RN
)
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, TR.TranNo, TR.TranName, TR.ResultNo, TR.ResultName
FROM tbl1 A
LEFT JOIN CTE_TR TR
    ON TR.ID = A.ID
ORDER BY A.ID, TR.RN
```

Result:

| ID | Name | TranNo | TranName | ResultNo | ResultName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | A1 | Order | R1 | Pending |
| 1 | Andy | A2 | Order | R2 | Succes |
| 1 | Andy | A3 | Order | null | null |
| 1 | Andy | A4 | Delivery | null | null |
| 2 | Lisa | A5 | Order | R3 | Succes |
| 2 | Lisa | A6 | Delivery | null | null |
| 2 | Lisa | A7 | Delivery | null | null |

See [this db<>fiddle>](https://dbfiddle.uk/H0S9nWmX).

Blanks can be inserted in place of nulls by wrapping some of the results with `ISNULL(xxx, '')`.

Eliminating repeated values is best left to the presentation layer, but if you must, you could possibly use `CASE` expressions that check for RN = 1. Note that ID would need to be converted to a string if you wanted to include blank values in the same column.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l_a_HGHv).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I expected, and I'll try to develop it according to my real needs. very grateful.